# Write a function that will return string after fetching message using FormatMessage

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, formatmessage

I wanted to write a function that will take error_code as argument and fetch the error message and the return the message. But for FormatMessage the memory allocated is cleared by using LocalFree(err_msg). Not sure how can this be dont along with returning.

```
static char* return_message(int error_code) {
   LPTSTR err_msg;
   FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK,
            0, error_code, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR)&err_msg, 0, 0);
  return err_msg;
```

I want to have a method similar to above. While in above case if we return err_msg it goes out of scope. Can anyone please give the proper function for this?

Comment: return `std::unique_ptr<char[], CustomDeleter>`, or `std::string` after local copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you're using C++ you can copy the resulting message into an `std::string` instance, free the C-string and return the copy. `std::string`'s destructor will take care of deallocation when its no longer used.

```
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

static std::string return_message(int error_code) {
   char* tmp_msg;
   FormatMessageA( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK,
            0, error_code, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPSTR)&tmp_msg, 0, 0);

   std::string err_msg(tmp_msg);
   LocalFree(tmp_msg);
   return err_msg;
}
```

Comment: The return value of `FormatMessageA()` is the number of characters output. I would suggest passing that to the `std::string` constructor as well, eg: `DWORD tmp_msg_len = FormatMessageA(...); std::string err_msg(tmp_msg, tmp_msg_len);` This way `std::string` doesn't have to waste time counting characters to figure out how many to copy. You should also consider using `try/catch` or `std::unique_ptr` to ensure `tmp_msg` is freed even if the `std::string` constructor throws an exception.